# Revision / backup software for folder?

Tags: backup, dropbox

I'm looking for a simple backup/revision software that will monitor a folder for new changes and make a backup of newly modified files? I have a folder with some text files, a few Word/Excel files and I'd like to keep backup files of them when they're modified. (It's no more than 50 mb).

I'd like what Dropbox does  but just locally (not to be stored on the cloud). Thank you.

Edit: I'm on Windows XP. And I'm looking for a freeware app, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I've found [FileHamster](http://www.filehamster.com/) to be very useful. It's commercial now but there's a older version out there that is free.

Edit: I got tired of the nagging messages on FileHamster and found [AutoVer](http://beanland.net.au/autover/) as a free alternative. The developer has recently returned to continue development of the project, with the possibility of making it open-source.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution you could:

1) run rsync out of a cron job on a regular basis.

2) use a version control system (like 'git' or 'svn') to track the files in the directory and check them in, which manages the version history well.

Comment: I'm on XP. I don't really want to bother with checking in files. Dropbox does exactly what I want, but I don't want to store anything online.

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify XP in your original post.

Comment: rsync would still work, btw, but it's a bit harder to automated on a regular schedule on XP.

Comment: @WesHardaker Does rsync keep track of a folder's revision history (and does it make it possible to revert a folder to a previous version)?

Comment: rsync doesn't, no, but that's what bullet #2 covered: how to do backups, etc, using a version control system.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has a free utility called [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) that's good for this sort of thing.

It can easily be scheduled to run at regular intervals with the system's Task Scheduler.

Comment: @Gabriel: FWIW, you can use SyncToy and Dropbox together in creative ways to implement a customized hybrid local+cloud backup strategy.

Answer (score 0):

[rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) you can use as a regular copy (to a local disk) or to a server. It copies only deltas (as rsync), but keeps versions with changes